# SQL table with constraint on multiple NULL

Tags: mysql, constraints

I am using MYSQL and I have a table of devices. Each device has, among the others, an ID, called `mac_address` (this is not the pk), and a column named `deleted_date`.

If a device **is not** active, its `deleted_date` equals to a timestamp, and then it should be ok to add a new device with the same `mac_address`.
If it's active, its `deleted_date` equals to NULL and then it should not be ok to add a new device with the same `mac_address`.

I found out that it was possible to have two devices that are still active with the same `mac_address`, which is wrong. After some research, I figured out that I can't compare NULL to NULL since it does not count as the same value.

I would appreciate an idea for how to get around this.

- Two devices with the same `mac_address`, and `deleted_date` is NULL: **WRONG**
- Two devices with the same `mac_address`, one `deleted_date` is NULL and the other has a value: **OK**
- Two devices with the same `mac_address`, and `deleted_date` has a value for both of them: **OK**

Right now this is the relevant part of the table creation and constraints:

```
'CREATE TABLE `iot_devices` (
  `pk` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `device_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `device_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `delete_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `mac_address` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pk`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idx_device_id` (`device_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idx_mac_address_delete_date` (`mac_address`,`delete_date`),
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will need to identify and solve the following:

- what are possible problems that we could already have
- how to handle an insert
- how to handle an update

### Possible problem

You might have several records with the same `mac_address` and `null` `delete_date`. You will need to make sure that you have a single record per each `mac_address` that has a `null` `delete_date`. If you want to use a `constraint` for `unique`, you can set the non-deleted records' `delete_date` to some date in the very distant future and will know that records having a `delete_date` in the future are not deleted. If that future date is a constant, then that would solve your problem, but this solution is not very elegant. I would still use the `null` date instead but then you need other measures.

### Triggers before insert or update

P.Salmon's answer describes this kind of approach, I will not duplicate it, but upvote his answer instead. The problem with triggers is that in the case when there are more records to be inserted/updated and the trigger throws an error early on, then some valid insertions or modifications will not happen.

### Problems with insert and update

The problem with `insert` is the possibility that the new record would match a `mac_address` with `null` `delete_date`. The problem with update is that the updated record would result with a duplicated `mac_address` with another record which has a `null` `delete_date`. You can do an [insert select](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html) or `update` with a condition like:

```
where not ((not (iot_devices.deleted_date is null)) and (iot_devices.mac_address = 'youvalue'))
```

### Handling older records as we go

You can update delete_date of older records as a trigger on your `insert` or `update`

### '' instead of null

You can change the type of your delete_date to `varchar` and have `''` to non-deleted values. Then you can use a constraint. However, searching by `delete_date` will become more difficult in this case.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I am looking more for a fix from now onwards, rather than change what is already there. I can easily fix the current database to be legit.

Comment: @MorZamir how would you like to fix it? What are your preferances? There are several ways to fix it.

Comment: add some constraint from now onwards that makes sure there is no other device with the same mac_address that is active when I try to insert a new device. for those who are already there, I will handle them.

Comment: @MorZamir if you want a quick fix, update the records having null as delete_date to 2100-12-31 59:59:59 and from there on you will know that whenever the delete_date is in the future, the record was not removed. Then you can create a constraint for (delete_date, mac_address to be unique) and this time it will work. However, in the application you will need to change the logic which assumes that null means not deleted, not null means deleted.

Comment: this is not a quick fix since it will require a lot of changes in many places in the code, like finding all the places where it checks if deleted is null, but it's a very smart solution and I think I will do it anyway! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this on an INSERT statement alone but you can with a trigger for example.

```
drop trigger if exists t;
delimiter $$

create trigger t before insert on t
for each row
begin
        declare vcount int default 0;
        select ifnull(count(*),0) into vcount from t where mac_address = new.mac_address and delete_date is null; 
       if vcount <> 0 then
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'An error occurred';
        end if;
end $$
delimiter ;
```

Note you will probably have to do something similar on an UPDATE.

Answer (score -1):

You are right NULL cannot be compared with NULL 
but you can compare '' with '' so

Use **''** empty string not **NULL** as default value